# getting property not found exception in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, google-cloud-datastore, jstl

I was trying to display list of entities but I get this error:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find property drug in class com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity
```

The way to display property is this:

```
 <c:forEach items="${drugtargets}" var="drugtarget">
<tr>
  <td>${drugtarget.drug}</td>
  <td>${drugtarget.target}</td>
</tr>
```

I checked my datastore and entities properties and I didn't see any error. My properties are drug and target. Could you please tell me what I should do ? Thanks.

```
Key drugKey = KeyFactory.createKey("DrugTarget", drug);

Entity drugtarget = new Entity("DrugTarget",drugKey);
drugtarget.setProperty("drug", drug);
drugtarget.setProperty("target", target);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't do GAE, but according to the [javadoc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Entity) of that `Entity` class, which tells that there's a [`getProperties()` method returning a `Map<String, Object>` with all properties](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/PropertyContainer#getProperties%28%29), then you should be able to access the individual properties as follows:

```html
<td>${drugtarget.properties.drug}</td>
<td>${drugtarget.properties.target}</td>
```

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, if this concerns user-controlled data, please keep in mind that this forms a potential XSS attack hole. You should be escaping user-controlled input using [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<c:out>` or `fn:escapeXml()`.

```html
<td><c:out value="${drugtarget.properties.drug}" /></td>
<td><c:out value="${drugtarget.properties.target}" /></td>
```

Comment: thank you again. I added fn:escapeXml() in order to prevent attacks. Using properties worked too.